# Bigquery find with SQL how much data of a table is in Active storage or Long term Storage

Tags: google-bigquery

In the BigQuery Console under Details I can see how much data of a BigQuery table is in Active Storage and how much in Long Term Storage.

[image: bigquery metadata table storage size]

How can I get this metadata via SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM <project_id>.<dataset_id>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
```

More info can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#partitions_view